Ideal intersection vs ideal multiplication in the definition of prime ideal
Suppose $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $A$ with the following property:

Given elements $x_0, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ of $A$ ($n \ge 0$), if $x_0 A \cap \cdots \cap x_{n-1} A \subseteq I$, then for some $0 \le j < n$, $x_j \in I$.

In other words: $I \ne A$ and given a finite subset of $A$, if $I$ contains all common multiples of those elements, then $I$ contains one of those elements.
Is this a well known class of ideals?

It is not hard to see that any prime ideal has this property.
However, so does $p^n \mathbb{Z}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ for any prime number $p$ and any integer $n > 1$.
The point seems to be that $I$ could be just big enough to contain $x^n$ but not big enough to contain $x$.
On the other hand, it is unclear to me whether there is any relationship between this class of ideals and primary ideals.
Ideals with this property are closely related to completely prime filters of the lattice of ideals: specifically, given such an ideal $I$, the set $F$ of all ideals $J \nsupseteq I$ is a completely prime filter, and every completely prime filter of the lattice of ideals arises in this way.

As with prime ideals, we can rewrite the property in terms of not necessarily principal ideals:

Given ideals $I_0, \ldots, I_{n-1}$ of $A$ ($n \ge 0$), if $I_0 \cap \cdots \cap I_{n-1} \subseteq I$, then for some $0 \le j < n$, $I_j \subseteq I$.

Clearly, this condition implies the version at the top of this post (by restricting to principal ideals).
Conversely, assume the condition for principal ideals only, and suppose given $I_0 \cap \cdots \cap I_{n-1} \subseteq I$.
For a contradiction, suppose also for all $0 \le j < n$, $I_j \nsubseteq I$.
That means we have $x_j \in A$ such that $x_j \in I_j$ and $x_j \notin I$.
But $x_0 A \cap \cdots \cap x_{n-1} A \subseteq I_0 \cap \cdots \cap I_{n-1} \subseteq I$, so the hypothesis gives $0 \le j < n$ such that $x_j \in I$ – contradicting the choice of $x_j$.
Hence, for some $0 \le j < n$, $I_j \subseteq I$.

Sorry I made a bad edit and reverted it. For $n=0$ we get precisely that $I \neq A$. So $n \geq 0$ is correct.

I guess the notion you are looking for is the notion of a "strongly irreducible ideal" from  the paper "Strongly irreducible ideals of a commutative ring" by William J. Heinzer, Louis J. Ratliff Jr. and David E. Rush
https://www.math.purdue.edu/~heinzer/preprints/irr15.pdf

Thank you. That does look related, but seems subtly different if the ring is not a PID. The mention of distributivity in the lattice of ideals is interesting – the failure of distributivity in general is also why I ended up looking into this!

@ChristianLomp I have convinced myself that my condition is in fact equivalent to the condition in that paper. It is a confusing proof by contradiction but I guess it's the same argument that shows that prime ideals can be defined by either element multiplication or ideal multiplication. If you post an answer I will accept.

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring and $x\in R$ an element. Denote by $\langle x \rangle = \{ rx : r\in R\}$ the principal ideal generated by $x$.
The following statements are equivalent for an ideal $I$ of $R$:

For $n\geq 1$ and $x_1,\ldots, x_n\in A$ with $\langle x_1\rangle \cap \cdots \cap \langle x_n\rangle \subseteq I$ there exists $1\leq i \leq n$, such that $x_i\in I$.
For ideals $A, B$ of $R$, such that $A\cap B\subseteq I$ one has $A\subseteq I$ or $B\subseteq I$.

Proof: $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ If $A\cap B\subseteq I$ and $A\not\subseteq I$, then fix an element $a\in A\setminus I$. For any $b\in B$ one has$\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle \subseteq A\cap B \subseteq I$. As $a\not\in I$, by $(1)$, $b\in I$. Thus $B\subseteq I$.
$(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ $n=1$ is trivial and for $n\geq 2$ one might choose $A=\langle x_1\rangle \cap \cdots \cap \langle x_{n-1}\rangle$ and $B=\langle x_n\rangle$ and use $(2)$ inductively.
An ideal $I$ with condition $(2)$ is called strongly irreducible by Heinzer et al. in "Strongly irreducible ideals of a commutative ring", https://math.purdue.edu/~heinzer/preprints/irr15.pdf
More generally, one might consider the set of ideals as a lattice, with $\cap$ being the infimum and $+$ the supremum. For a lattice, or even more generally a meet-semilattice $L$ with meet $\wedge$, one can call an element $p\in L$ irreducible if whenever $p=a\wedge b$, then $p=a$ or $p=b$ and can call $p$ strongly irreducible if whenever $a\wedge b \leq p$, then $a\leq p$ or $b\leq p$. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Important_lattice-theoretic_notions where strongly irreducible is called meet-prime.).
